# Filtering out objects of a deeply nested data structure in Typescript / Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, tree, filtering

I want to filter out of a deeply nested data structure all the objects that match a rule. I know there are similar examples to delete a particular key of nested object, but I haven't been able to implement the solutions. The data structure will never be infinite, but it can be very deep (more than 10 levels)

Here are the types:

```
    export type DataStructure = Entry[]

    export interface Entry {
        id: string
        text: string
        type: 1 | 2
        children?: Entry[]
    }
```

So an entry array could be:

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    type: 1,
    text: "Node 1",
    children: [
      {
        id: "1.1",
        type: 1,
        text: "Node 1.1",       
        children: [
          {
            id: "1.1.1",            
            type: 2,
            text: "Node 1.1.1",
            children: []
          }
        ],        
      },
      {
        id: "1.2",
        type: 1,
        text: "Node 1.2",
        children: [
          {
            id: "1.2.1",
            type: 2,
            text: "Node 1.2.1",
            children: [],
          },
          {
            id: "1.2.2",
            type: 1,
            text: "Node 1.2.2",
            children: [],
          }
        ]        
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The expected output array, provided the rule `type !== 2` would be:

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    type: 1,
    text: "Node 1",
    children: [      
      {
        id: "1.2",
        type: 1,
        text: "Node 1.2",
        children: [          
          {
            id: "1.2.2",
            type: 1,
            text: "Node 1.2.2",
            children: [],
          }
        ]        
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I haven't been able to implement recursion to do it, the arrays keep showing all the entries
I don't mind using `lodash` if there is a built-in function. Thanks!

Comment: *"all the objects that match a rule"* What rules exactly? Please proved all the input parameters and a sample expected output

Comment: Apologies! I posted by mistake while I had not finished. The rule is `type !== 2`, and I've edited so you can see the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter based on `type`:

```
function test() {
      const test = [
        {
          id: "1",
          type: 1,
          text: "Node 1",
          children: [
            {
              id: "1.1",
              type: 1,
              text: "Node 1.1",
              children: [
                {
                  id: "1.1.1",
                  type: 1,
                  text: "Node 1.1.1",
                  children: []
                }
              ],
            },
            {
              id: "1.2",
              type: 2,
              text: "Node 1.2",
              children: [
                {
                  id: "1.2.1",
                  type: 2,
                  text: "Node 1.2.1",
                  children: [],
                },
                {
                  id: "1.2.2",
                  type: 2,
                  text: "Node 1.2.2",
                  children: [],
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ];

      console.log(JSON.stringify(filterData(test, 2), 0, 4))

      console.log('test: ', test);

}
```

and filter method:

```
function filterData(data, type) {
    var r = data.filter(function(o) {
      if (o.children)
        o.children = filterData(o.children, type);
      return o.type != type
    })
    return r;
}
```

Comment: To my understanding `o.children` should always return `true` since an empty array is not a falsy statement. See `console.log(!![]) => true`.